# How do I create the project outside the /var/www/ directory?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, directory

I've a Ubuntu server with static IP for testing purpose, I'd like to create a project (for example hello-world) outside the /var/www/ directory, let's say in this location(/home/username/webroot/hello-world/). It should be accessible via browser like this http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/hello-world/ How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an Alias:

```
Alias /hello-world /home/www/foo
<Directory "/home/www/foo">
    Options -MultiViews -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have install a LAMP on ubuntu 14.04, I would like to share a folder from external drive. I red that should use 'alias', so I open up the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf' and add as user rekire mentioned. always getting

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test on this server.
any tip?

thanks

Comment: which file would I add this to?

Comment: Not absolutely sure what I had in mind 10 years ago! But I would guess the virtual host where you want that special alias.

Answer (score 2):

Enable [FollowSymlinks](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) in your Apache-config and make a symbolic link on your file system.

```
ln -s /path/to/your/project /var/www/projectname
```

And replacing the content is easy, without having to reload the server

```
rm /var/www/projectname
ln -s /path/to/your/project-v2 /var/www/projectname
```

Answer (score 1):

you configure a virtual host in the configuration file of your apache: apache2.conf or httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerPath /hello-world
        DocumentRoot /home/username/webroot/hello-world
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think your ServerName ist wrong. You entered a path but ServerName expects a host name.